# Show content depending on url

Tags: php, html, web

Is it possible to determine what to show depending on the URL?

I have an index file which is:

```
<?php include './includes/header.php'; ?>
<?php include './includes/menu.php'; ?>
<?php include './includes/content.php'; ?>
<?php include './includes/sidebar.php'; ?>
<?php include './includes/footer.php'; ?>
```

Note: I have different "`content.php`"'s

Is it possible to do something like:

```
If Url = url {
    show only content for the url
}
```

and then have case system like

```
case: home.php
      show some
```

etc

I know Wordpress can do it. Is it possible with PHP and MySQL and HTML?

EDIT: Instead of content.php i would want show the desired HTML code gotten from my db

Comment: It is possible. But can you explain like what you want to compare exactly . You mean like http://www.google.com = http://www.google.com ??

Comment: What Exactly you want to do?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the same `include` for that?

Comment: Have you tried something? What kind of URLs do you have (show at least two urls you want have on your site)?

Comment: of course you can, look at $_SERVER variable to get the desired url part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying from database.

> I don't recommend MySql, and I hope you learn PDO instead, but just
>   for this example

```
function get_me_title($page) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM title WHERE title = $page";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
foreach($result as $row) {

return $row[$page];
}

}
```

Now, you can use function .`get_me_title('whatever')` to query from database, and echo below

```
if(isset($_GET['page_id'])) {

$page = $_GET['page_id'];




switch($page) {

case "contact";
echo get_me_title('contact');
break; 

case "about";
echo get_me_title('about');
break; 


case "portofolio";
echo  get_me_title('portofolio')
break; 

default:
echo 'you are in home page';

}
}else {echo '404 ERROR! The Page you have requested does not exist';}
```

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking of that i could put my html into an db and then get depending on the side their on!

Comment: Check it and tell me, if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Ye, something like this, i would like to use PDO but we cant (school project! ) :/

Comment: Well you can check if PDO is installed in your schools server

Comment: I am using WAMP, and it comes pre-packed with mysql

Comment: Ok, sorry, we noticed that now, anyway, our teacher is like: you can only use the commands were been trough.! Thank you so much for your answere. One last, i should put this in my index.php aka holder file right ?

Comment: Ok, but I suggest you create one file called, anything like `pages.php` and include it to your page, and maybe if some day you created, another page, then you can include it as well, so all the url will work for that page too

Comment: What exactly do you mean ?

Comment: Well, think like this, if you include the codes, in index page, then you will only show, what you need to show, as long as the `index.php?page=` is equal to something, you can not for example show what you can display in...lets say, adress.php but if you include this codes in all your pages, you can even show from your database, on adress.php

if it does not make sense to you, just skip it, and include it in index page as you have asked

Answer (score 2):

Use this function to see your current page. Then use the "switch" case for proper include file:

```
## Get Current Page / Section
function cur_page()
{
    $cur_page='';
    if(isset($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) && $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']!='')
    {
        $temp_var1 = explode('/', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        $cur_page = $temp_var1[count($temp_var1)-1];
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) && $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']!='')
    {
        $temp_var1 = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
        $cur_page = $temp_var1[count($temp_var1)-1];
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='')
    {
        $temp_var1 = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        $cur_page = $temp_var1[count($temp_var1)-1];
        $temp_var2 = explode('?', $cur_page);
        $cur_page = $temp_var2[0];
    }
    else if(isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) && $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']!='')
    {
        $temp_var1 = explode('/', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
        $cur_page = $temp_var1[count($temp_var1)-1];
    }
    return $cur_page;
}//end func.....
```

Comment: This functions covers all end, which ever is available `(PHP_SELF, SCRIPT_NAME, REQUEST_URI, SCRIPT_FILENAME)` - this is because some variables are available on some environment.

Comment: Yeah, i was thinking of that i could put my html into an db and then get depending on the side their on!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including content.php, you can include needed page.
For example, if You build Your urls, where, for example, $_GET['page'] will refer to needed page, then simply You can do this.

```
$availablePages = array('default' => 'home', 'about');
if (isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], $availablePages) {
    $page = $_GET['page'] . '.php';
} else {
    $page = $availablePages['default'] . '.php';
}

include $page;
```